# Function pointer "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, function, pointers, scope, functor

At the top of the `main` function in a C++ script, I define a function pointer based on a command-line argument as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  // Set integration method.
  const char* method = argv[argc - 1];
  if (strcmp(method, "euler") == 0)
    {
      std::vector<double> (*get_V)(const std::vector<double> &, const double,
                                   const std::vector<double> &);
      get_V = euler;
    }
  else if (strcmp(method, "exact") == 0)
    {
      std::vector<double> (*get_V)(const std::vector<double> &, const double,
                                   const std::vector<double> &);
      get_V = exact;
    }
  else
    {
      throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid method supplied at command line.");
    }
```

My goal here is to set the variable `get_V` to be a pointer to either the function `euler` or the function `exact`, depending on the command-line argument.

Later, still inside the `main` function, I call `get_V` as follows:

```
V = get_V(V, Delta_t, dV_dt);
```

When I try to compile, this line -- in which I call `get_V` -- raises the following error:

```
(master)dbliss@nx3[dopa_net]> g++ -O3 hansel.cpp -o hansel.o
hansel.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hansel.cpp:65: error: ‘get_V’ was not declared in this scope
```

This makes no sense to me.  I *did* declare `get_V` in this scope.  What's going on?  (I can post my entire main function if that'd be helpful, but it's fairly long.)

Comment: You declared `get_V` inside a block. When that block ends, all the locals in it go out of scope.

Comment: @JamesRoot ah, i'm used to python, where if statements don't define a separate scope.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare two different variables each named `get_V`, both locally inside the scope of the `if` statements. Once the code inside the `if` statement is done, those variables are no more, they have gone out of scope.

The simple solution? Declare the variable *outside* the `if` statements, and only do the assignments in the `if` statement bodies.

Comment: if `euler` and `exact` end up taking different arguments, what would my best option here be?  is there any way to have a declaration inside a conditional block live on just outside it?

Comment: @dbliss Then you should probably start to rethink your design. Or do the easy way out, and just call the functions inside their `if` statements.

Comment: calling the functions inside those if statements won't work.  i suppose i could put new if statements at the time of the function call (within a loop).  the design doesn't seem unreasonable in any way to me.  i have different numerical methods that can be used within a script.  i want to specify which method to use at the command line.  each method is associated with a function.

Comment: isn't the answer here just to make the function pointer a global variable within the if statement?

Comment: @dbliss unless it's a requirement, nobody says you *must* put that check and assignment first thing in the program, you can have that check much later after you done everything else, and all that's left is to call the functions.

Comment: @dbliss And making "a global variable within the if statement" is kind of a  contradiction, either the variable is defined globally, locally inside the function, or locally inside a code block.

Comment: hmm, no, the function, like i said, is in a loop, so there's no point at which "all that's left is to call the functions."  also, it's not a contradiction.  there's nothing oxymoronic about wanting to conditionally set a global variable.  it would be trivial to do what i want to do in Python.  i guess C++ is fundamentally limited here?

Comment: but i guess since C++ is so fast, having the if statements in the loop won't really hurt me.

Comment: profiling has revealed that putting the if statement in the for loop does imply a substantial performance cost.  there's got to be a way around this . . . it seems silly to have to have two separate scripts, just because c++ doesn't allow conditional declaration of a function.

Comment: @dbliss It might be because of the string comparisons. You can put the comparisons outside the main loop, and just set some integer flag and only check that flag inside the loop.